# PHP Security and XSS attacks - Getting Error Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request

Tags: php, security, xss, code-injection

I'm going through my site and doing a security audit. I've simply accepted the fact that I need to sanitize ALL user input, but I've never really stopped and experimented with what's really going on. I'm starting to experiment now.

I have a typical contact form on a PHP page. It's `_POST`ing data. `$_POST["first_name"];` etc.

I do this `$firstName = htmlspecialchars($_POST["first_name"]);` to sanitize and display a message like the one below.

```
echo $firstName . ', thank you for your interest. We'll be in touch soon!'
```

I started to play with this and if I enter something such as `<script>alert('hello')</script>` in the first name field, `htmlspecialchars` does it's job and coverts the tags.

When I remove `htmlspecialchars` the script doesn't get converted and it displays in the source as `<script>alert('hello')</script>` BUT, it does not execute.

My question is, why doesn't this execute? Isn't this basically what an XSS attack would do? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Did you check the javascrpt console for errors?

Comment: @symcbean - I just checked. Yes, there is an error. "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request."

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars($_POST["first_name"], ENT_QUOTES);` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I tried this in Chrome I saw an error in the console:

> Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.

So it's possible modern browsers do this check to prevent it.  You should continue to sanitize your input regardless of course, but check your console and you will probably see this.

Comment: I just checked and saw the same error. So, in theory, this is how an XSS attack would take place, correct?

Comment: @Paul try it in Internet Explorer (an older version) which may not have such a sophisticated check.  Other than that, read up on how XSS attacks are made.  They can be made in so many ways .. the only limit is your imagination.

Comment: Since [Chrome 11](http://peter.sh/2011/02/chrome-11-a-renewed-xss-filter-and-vertical-text-for-multiple-column-layouts/), it includes an XSS filter. Many other browsers don't, and XSS filters can't catch anything ([persistent](https://startpage.com/do/search?cmd=process_search&cat=web&query=persistent+xss) XSS in particular).